# can't find the application on windows 10 store

Tags: wpf, windows-10

i'm using windows 8 with visual studio 2013.
i made some changes on wpf app,i made all the steps from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036.aspx
 to upload the app to the store.
the app is in the store but only windows 8 users can see it.
the problem is that windows 10 users can't see the app and install it.
do i need to use visual studio 2015 in order to make the app uwp?

thanks for helpers

Comment: If it's in the Win8 store it should be visible on a Win10 device. What's the store link?

Comment: windows 10 link is - https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrdk217 but if you search it by the app name you will not find it

Answer (score 0):

If I view your app in the store it comes with a message saying it is "currently not available".
This might explain why it is not showing in search results.

With any store listing problem like this you should first start by contacting store support. They should be able to tell you: why you can't see an app in search (noting of course that they won't tell you why you're app has a specific position in search results and that even an exact search for an apps name may not put it on the first page of results); if there are any known problems; or if it's somehow related to your account.

Comment: the is not available because it's only for region Israel (that's what the customer want)